# Postgresql 11 - Create Procedure to Execute COPY function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, sqlbulkcopy

I'm currently trying to create a procedure to automatically copy data into my database when I call the procedure. However, every time I call it I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  column "name" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT format('COPY test(%L) FROM %s CSV HEADER', name, '/Us...
```

How does the column not exist? Here's everything I've written out:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE 
test_insert() AS
$$ 

BEGIN 

EXECUTE format('COPY test(%L) FROM %s CSV HEADER', name, '/Users/Receiving.csv');


END; 

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `name` without single quotes, it is interpreted as a column name in the (tacit) `SELECT` statement

```
SELECT format('...', name, '...')
```

that PL/pgSQL runs when you execute your function.

Since this `SELECT` statement does not have a `FROM` clause, you get the observed error.

The solution is to use a string literal instead, i.e. write `'name'` instead of 'name'.